# Laravel: clearing one cache store clears all

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis

In my Laravel application, I have multiple cache stores, all using Redis, defined like so:

```php
// config/cache.php
'stores' => [
    ...
    'geo-index' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
    ],

    'batches' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
    ],
    ...
],
```

Which does work... kinda...
If I look inside Redis `KEYS *`, I do get everything stored, however, I can't distinguish which value is in which store (by looking at key prefix), also, more importantly, no matter how I clear one store:

```php
# like so
php artisan cache:clear <store>

#or so
cache()->store($store)->clear();
```

all stores get cleared, and Redis `KEYS *` returns an empty array.

I need this in order to be able to clear one set of data while keeping others.

Am I using this wrongly? or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

As all of your Cache stores are using Redis, when you use clear() or flush() it will clear all Redis cache. Instead, you can define a single Redis cache in stores array and use Tags to group your cache and remove them at your convenience. For example to store items in geo-index, use:

```
Cache::store('redis')->tags(['geo-index'])->put('foo', 'bar');
```

to remove all cache tagged as geo-index, use:

```
Cache::store('redis')->tags(['geo-index'])->flush();
```

Comment: Ok, so I guess I misunderstood this line : `You may even define multiple stores for the same cache driver to group types of items stored in your caches.` (Comment block in `config/cache.php`)?

Comment: What I found you can group them using different store if you use different prefix for different store, but clear() removes all caches of the same driver. Lets see if anyone else can point out a different solution .

Comment: From the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#removing-items-from-the-cache
"Flushing the cache does not respect your configured cache "prefix" and will remove all entries from the cache. Consider this carefully when clearing a cache which is shared by other applications."